# Socket.IO Client doesn't work properly on 3g/4g connection

Tags: websocket, socket.io, intermittent, 3g-network

I've been searching over the web about the problem I'm having with socketio client on 3g/4g networks. It seems to connect, but doesn't keep connected for long, it keeps connected for about 60 seconds then disconnect, connecting again when the reconnecting attempt events trigger, but reepats the above behavior.

Does anyone know why this happens or how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Heres a sample of the code i'm using to start de socket:

```
var socketOpts = { 
                        reconnect: true,
                        reconnectionDelayMax : 2500,
                        timeout : 10000,
                        transport: ['polling','websocket']
                     };

    socket = io.connect( $scope.socket_addr, socketOpts );

    showMessage( true, "Aguardando conexão com o servidor!", true );

    /* Abaixo estão os eventos que o Socket pode disparar durante o funcionamento do app */

    /* Quando o Socket conectar no servidor */
    socket.on("connect", function() 
    {
        $scope.socket_connected = true;
        /* Agora que o socket já conectou, posso alterar o tempo de ping */
        socket.io.engine.pingInterval = 3000;
        socket.io.engine.pingTimeout = 5000;
        showMessage( false, "", false );
        console.log( "WS conectado" );
    });
```

Comment: That's how mobile connections work and why the term "occasionally connected" is used. You'll always lose the connection because you entered an elevator, a dead zone *even in a city*, your phone has disconnection issues or you moved to the other side of the house. *Don't* try to keep the connection open

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this code belongs to an Cordova app thats usually used in in the street's open sky. It shoud be connected more time, doesn't? I mean, the websocket's should work exactly to keep an connection open, or am i wrong?

Comment: @Fernando Rebêllo I noticed the same behaviour too. Every minute connects with a new socket.id. Did you found a solution? It works great over wifi ... not LTE, 4g ...

Comment: @InêsGomes, I noticed that the socket used to close because when the user locked  the screen, the OS was hibernating the app, so I added a backgroundMode plugin to avoid the app from hibernating, it consumes more battery, but that wasn't a problem to me. I also decreased the ping interval to server, so It takes less time to realize that the connection is gone and open a new one. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks@Fernando Rebêllo. :-) I think I will try to increasing time out

Answer (score 0):

Setting these options to delay the reconnection worked  :-)

```
val opts = IO.Options()
opts.reconnection = true
opts.reconnectionDelay = 2000
opts.timeout = 60000
val socket = IO.socket(url, opts)
```

Or in Ionic

```
socketConf: {
    url: 'http://your.Server.url',
    options: { reconnection: true, reconnectionDelay: 3000, timeout: 60000 }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @InêsGomes, thank you for replying these question, although my problem was Android sleep state killing the connection, other users might be having these issues due to this times. Once again thank you for sharing your solution!!

Comment: Hi @FernandoRebêllo What  backgroundMode plugin worked for you?

Comment: Hi @InêsGomes, I used katzer backgroundMode plugin, but, keep in mind that this plugin only works for Android, actually, it works for iOS too, but apple rejects the publishing for some technical reasons. https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @FernandoRebêllo I had lots of problems with that plugin. But solved it this way https://github.com/irceline/aq-mobile-be/issues/94#issuecomment-464293865 and with wake locks